# Do I really have to use a global variable for this recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a recursive function that happens to be a for loop

```
function deepFindGroup(groupName, currentGroup) {
    console.log("Testing");
    for (e in currentGroup) {

        if (currentGroup[e].intName == groupName) {
            console.log(currentGroup[e]["Members"]);
            return currentGroup[e]["Members"];
        } else if (currentGroup[e]["Members"]) {
            return deepFindGroup(groupName, currentGroup[e]["Members"]);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems I cannot handle every possibility with a meaningful return statement. If, say, currentGroup[e].intName is not equal to groupName and no child of that branch has a member property (It has no child at all in this case). It ends up returning undefined. The only solution I can think of is making a global variable, I'm trying to avoid that.

edit:
The function is supposed to return a given branch in a tree. The tree is made up of objects (with an intName properties) that contain "Members" which can themselves be objects containing other Members. Members can also contain nothing but still have an intName.

Looks like that:

```
Gengroup_1--intName: Gengroup_1
          |
          --Members-- nochild -- intName: nochild
                    |
                    --Gengroup_2--intName: Gengroup2
                                 |
                                 --Members-- object -- intName: object
                                           |
                                           -- anotherObject -- intName: anotherObject
```

Comment: What is the function supposed to do?

Comment: return the location of a given branch in a tree

Comment: More specific, please. Anyway, you’ll probably want a value to signal that nothing was found (e.g. `null`) and to check for that before returning from a child find.

Comment: What do you mean with ` location of a given branch`? Do you want the path or the actual group, without reference to the location? Could you also please post a sample of the haystack?

Comment: I'm new to data structures, if that is even one. I have tried to be more informative with my update.

Comment: is group an `object`?

Comment: The whole tree is an object containing objects. groupName is a string and currentGroup is an object. Your solution works, I'm trying to determine which is the best.

Comment: If the key of the Groups in members is === intName, you could do it even simpler, by first checking for `currentGroup[groupName]`

Comment: You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `result` when entering the function, stop iteration, when something was found:

```js
function deepFindGroup(groupName, currentGroup) {
  var result = null;

  for (e in currentGroup) {
    if (currentGroup[e].intName === groupName) {
      result = currentGroup[e]["Members"];
    } else if (currentGroup[e]["Members"]) {
      result = deepFindGroup(groupName, currentGroup[e]["Members"]);
    }
    
    if (result || result === undefined) break;
  }
  
  return result;
}

var group = {
  one: {
    intName: 'one',
    Members: {
      one_one: {
        intName: 'one_one',
      }
    }
  },
  two: {
    intName: 'two',
    Members: {
      two_one: {
        intName: 'two_one',
        Members: {}
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(deepFindGroup('one', group)) // -> {one_one: {intName: 'one_one'}}
console.log(deepFindGroup('one_one', group)) // -> undefined (members are undefined)
console.log(deepFindGroup('two_one', group)) // -> {}
console.log(deepFindGroup('two_two', group)) // -> null
```

Keep in mind, when `currentGroup[e]["Members"]` of a matched group is `undefined`, you will get `undefined` as result, so if the result is `undefined` or an `array` or `whatever` is meant to be in members, then the group was matched, if `null` it was not found.

Answer (score 1):

Your function will not try multiple branches if one branch does not yield a find. It returns even if no match was found. Instead it should allow the `for` loop to continue so that a new search can be done via another branch.

Here is how you could do it, assuming that the found value will never be `undefined` itself:

```
function deepFindGroup(groupName, currentGroup) {
    var result;
    console.log("Testing");
    for (var e in currentGroup) {
        if (currentGroup[e].intName == groupName) {
            console.log(currentGroup[e]["Members"]);
            return currentGroup[e]["Members"];
        } else if (currentGroup[e]["Members"]) {
            // Don't return before you have looked at the result:
            result = deepFindGroup(groupName, currentGroup[e]["Members"]);
            if (result !== undefined) return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure that your variables are declared. You did not declare `e`, so it was global, and so the different recursion instances of the function scopes would be changing the same `e` variable, leading to erratic behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the e, I had no idea. Is there any official source that can confirm this?

Comment: @DominicGrenier This is a pretty well known JS feature: if you don't use the `var` keyword it will be declared in the global scope. As you asked for the *oficial* source, here it is: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/

Comment: Doesn't get more official than ECMAScript's documentation.
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-iteration-statements